# iOS QA automation tool - clicking on system settings

Tags: appium, ios

Is any iOS automation framework able to go to system settings and check some settings ex click on wireless networks ?

I really need some automated interacting . Is appium able to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Appium can't do that, SeeTest from Experitest might be able to give you access to wireless network settings.

Answer (score 1):

Sikuli can automate this (in the emulator on the Mac).

*SikuliX automates anything you see on the screen of your desktop computer running Windows, Mac or some Linux/Unix. It uses image recognition powered by OpenCV to identify and control GUI components. This is handy in cases when there is no easy access to a GUI's internals or the source code of the application or web page you want to act on.*

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Appium, but [WebDriverAgent](https://github.com/facebook/WebDriverAgent/) certainly can interact with any app or the OS home screen, settings, etc.  Appium does support WebDriverAgent as one of its backends, but I don't know if Appium adds some limitations or if it exposes all of WebDriverAgent's functionality.